# Can I make my CSS depend on a class not being present?

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS:

```
a.button:hover,
.mini-menu > li > a:hover {
    xxx
    }
```

Is there a way I can make this hover effect work for the button ONLY if the button does not have a class of "disabled"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [negation pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) : `:not(selector)`

```
a:not(.disabled).button:hover,
.mini-menu > li > a:not(.disabled):hover { ... }
```

(Requires a [supporting browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3anot).)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS3 `:not()` selector, but of course this has cross-browser compatibility implentations:

```
a.button:not(.disabled):hover,
.mini-menu > li > a:hover {
    xxx
}
```

Answer (score 1):

thy is can be done by the  `:not(.disabled)` selector.

Set the css for all elements that don't have `.disabled` class

**The :`not(selector)`** selector matches every element that is NOT the specified element/selector.

[image]

**Note**:IE8 and earlier do not support the

Answer (score 1):

Except `:not` selector, which is suggested here, you can also simply override  hover class for `a.button` with `disabled` class (may be usefull if you support IE7 and 8):

```
a.button:hover,
.mini-menu > li > a:hover {
    xxx
}

a.button.disabled:hover {
   //css to set non-hover style
}
```

[Simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BchT2/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `:not(.disabled)` selector.

Answer (score 0):

Besides `:not()` - Another approach would be to leverage CSS Specificity and reset the styling with a higher scoring "disabled" class.

```
a.button.disabled:hover,
.disabled.mini-menu > li > a:hover {
   xxx- disabled properties that won't be over ridden by below.
}


a.button:hover,
.mini-menu > li > a:hover {
    xxx
}
```

Working demo
http://jsfiddle.net/bKyr3/